# Sharing of training programme?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if posting about sharing of fitness programme relevant? As we could share and learn from each other that way. With the sharing of our personnal training we will be able to learn what type of exercise we are missing out or may even learn new exercise which can be of good use to our body.

While we share our training programme, there will reach a time where you will be bored of your own programme and will think of something new at that moment we can read on how other people train and innovate on new training programme for urself.

Comment: You can ask questions about your training program, if you have a specific goal in mind. Then other users are free to offer alternatives, but simply "heej, here's my training program, do you like it?" is not going to happen. Also, please try to use proper English, you isn't u and ppl isn't people...

Comment: Sorry I am a little too use to short form will change that habit of mine. Thanks will post on training programme next few day. Getting use to my old programme and have not seen any improvement on my body so thinking on changing them.

Comment: You are also free to head into the [chat] and discuss this with other people too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a particular fitness program that you're just dying to share with people for whatever reason, the Q&A format of the StackExchange network isn't really well suited for it, nor is it intended for it. Instead, feel free to discuss it in the chat room, or if you want to write something up about it, talk to one of the moderators (IvoFlipse, MattChan, Greg, or myself) about maybe putting together a blog post about it.

All of us are here (one would assume) because we have some level of interest in fitness, exercise, or general well-being. However, this is a question and answer site, so unless a post is made in the form of a specific and answerable question, it will be flagged and deleted.